# How to point rhel kickstart iso source to local DVD

Tags: redhat, kickstart

Somehow because of driver issue. I am unable get iso source over network. 
Just wondering if I can point it to a DVD media for the iso installation.

Instead of "url --url http://server/path" maybe "url --url /mountpoint" in the ks.cfg file?

Answer (score 3):

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax

> install (optional)
>
> The default installation mode. You must specify the type of installation from cdrom, harddrive, nfs, liveimg, or url (for FTP, HTTP, or HTTPS installations). The install command and the installation method command must be on separate lines.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> install
> cdrom
> ```
>
> cdrom - Install from the first optical drive on the system.

Note: I did not test this and haven't done it for a *long* time.